# How to build an object based off of a string enum?

Tags: typescript

For example:

```
enum App {
  App1 = "my-app1",
  App2 = "my-app2",
}

const AppPaths: {
  [ App.App1 ]: string;
  [ App.App2 ]: string;
} = {
  [ App.App1 ]: "/some/path/to/app1",
  [ App.App2 ]: "/some/path/to/app2",
};
```

This works, but it's verbose. I'd like to simplify `AppPaths` so that it is essentially:

```
const AppPaths: { [ key: keyof App ]: string } = ...
```

This gives the error:

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

So I tried with a mapped object type:

```
const AppPaths: { [ key in keyof App ]: string } = ...

// or

const AppPaths: { [ key in keyof typeof App ]: string } = ...
```

Both of which give the error:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and '[ App.App1 ]' does not exist in type '{ readonly [x: number]: string; toString: string; charAt: string; charCodeAt: string; concat: string; indexOf: string; lastIndexOf: string; localeCompare: string; match: string; replace: string; search: string; ... 39 more ...; [Symbol.iterator]: string; }

Is it possible to simplify this object's type declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Given the [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

```
enum App {
  App1 = "my-app1",
  App2 = "my-app2",
}
```

the type `App` is the type you're looking to [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over.  It is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of values in the enum, similar to `"my-app1" | "my-app2"`. That leads to:

```
const AppPaths: { [K in App]: string } = {
  [App.App1]: "/some/path/to/app1",
  [App.App2]: "/some/path/to/app2",
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggDnKBvAUFWCCMUC8UBEEAngLQCGW+ANGhnAEy4HHkL3UoC+KKAxgPYgAzgBc6ABTIiAFkIBcyKAG0A0lACWIOgF0FogE6aA5lE5NU6JfDgA6a5l0EA9EP4RgTuFOlOR-JxRwmByW1nZsjvgubh5eMr7+gew0nADcQA)